# How can I implement a route about multicast?

Tags: apache-camel

I have the scenario below.

1. Request Web Services from client system. This request is that the file will be copied.
2. Receive request by cxf component in application.
3. Response the return code that means success after receiving request immediately.
4. After send response, the application will fetch the file.

So, I implemented route.

```
<route>
    <from uri="cxf:bean:FileTransferServiceEndPoint"/>
    <multicast parellelProcessing="true">
        <toD uri="direct:bean"/>
        <toD uri="direct:fetchFile"/>
    </multicast>
</route>
<route>
    <from uri="direct:bean"/>
    <bean method="process" ref="returnMsg"/>
    <end>
</route>
<route>
    <from uri="direct:fetchFile"/>
    <pollEnrich>
        <simple>file:/test/inBox</simple>
    </pollEnrich>
    <toD uri="file:/test/outBox"/>
</route>
```

I faced to have some problem.
Originally, I think that response will be return by returnMsg Bean.
But Response Message was not respond until the file is completely processed.
I want the message delivered immediately to the client. And at the same time, I want the files to be processed.

How should I implement a route to fulfill my scenario?
Please let me know this solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using SEDA component (take a look at the option waitForTaskToComplete) or WireTap EIP (it makes a "lite" copy of the message but you can customize its behavior) to fetch the file.

PS 1.: Caution with the usage of `pollEnrich` without setting a timeout.
PS 2.: Depending upon the way you receive the body message, you may face a stream closed issue by using it more than once, as you end up doing in multicast.

Comment: I am considering wiretap for this problem. But I don’t understand second issue you said. Please let me know detail scenario about second. Thank you.

Comment: This might help you understand: [Stream caching](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/stream-caching.html)

Comment: you don't have to worried about the streams as you are copying the exchange with wireTap

Answer (score 0):

If you want your "direct" routes to be executed independently of each other, consider to use `wireTap`

```
<route>
    <from uri="cxf:bean:FileTransferServiceEndPoint"/>
    <wireTap uri="direct:bean"/>
    <to uri="direct:fetchFile"/>
</route>
```

from the "Camel in Action" book:

> By using the wireTap method in the Java DSL, you can send a copy of the exchange
>   to a secondary destination without affecting the behavior of the rest of the route